# Swift - Multipeer Connectivity "type "MPCManager" does not conform to protocol 'MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate'

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I am having trouble fully implementing MCNearbyServiceBroswerDelegate and MCNearbyServiceAdvertisingDelegate into my view controller file.

I have the MCSession values populating in my code, the only error I am getting is:

"Type 'MCPManager' does not conform to protocol 'MCNearbyServiceBroswerDelegate'"

I have looked at Apple's documentation and have fully implemented all of the delegate methods for the protocol.  I am at a loss.

```
 import MultipeerConnectivity

protocol MPCManagerDelegate {
func foundPeer()

func lostPeer()

func invitationWasReceived(fromPeer: String)

func connectedWithPeer(peerID: MCPeerID)
}

class MPCManager: NSObject, MCSessionDelegate, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate {

var delegate: MPCManagerDelegate?
var session: MCSession!
var peer: MCPeerID!
var browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser!
var advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser!
var foundPeers = [MCPeerID]()
//var invitationHandler: ((Bool, MCSession!)->Void)!


var invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession) -> Void = { success, session in }

override init() {

    peer = MCPeerID(displayName: UIDevice.currentDevice().name)
    session = MCSession(peer: peer)

    browser = MCNearbyServiceBrowser(peer: peer, serviceType: "appcoda-mpc")
    browser.delegate = self

    advertiser = MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser(peer: peer, discoveryInfo: nil, serviceType: "appcoda-mpc")
    advertiser.delegate = self

    super.init()

    session.delegate = self

}


func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, foundPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withDiscoveryInfo info: [String : String]?) {
    foundPeers.append(peerID)

    delegate?.foundPeer()

}


func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, lostPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    for (index, aPeer) in foundPeers.enumerate() {
        if aPeer == peerID {
            foundPeers.removeAtIndex(index)
            break
        }
    }

    delegate?.lostPeer()
}

func browser(browser: MCNearbyServiceBrowser, didNotStartBrowsingForPeers error: NSError) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

func sendData(dictionaryWithData dictionary: Dictionary<String, String>, toPeer targetPeer: MCPeerID) -> Bool {
    let dataToSend = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(dictionary)
    let peersArray = NSArray(object: targetPeer)
    //var error: NSError?

    if self.session.connectedPeers.count > 0 {
        //if let msg = self.messageField.text!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
        do {
            try self.session.sendData(dataToSend, toPeers: peersArray as! [MCPeerID], withMode: MCSessionSendDataMode.Reliable)
        } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)

        }
    }

    return true
}

func advertiser(advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser!, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID!, withContext context: NSData!, invitationHandler: ((Bool, MCSession!) -> Void)!) {
    self.invitationHandler = invitationHandler

    delegate?.invitationWasReceived(peerID.displayName)
}

func session(session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID
    , didChangeState state: MCSessionState) {
    switch state{
    case MCSessionState.Connected:
        print("Connected to session: \(session)")
        delegate?.connectedWithPeer(peerID)

    case MCSessionState.Connecting:
        print("Connecting to session: \(session)")

    default:
        print("Did not connect to session: \(session)")
    }
}

func advertiser(advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didNotStartAdvertisingPeer error: NSError) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveData data: NSData, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) {
    let dictionary: [String: AnyObject] = ["data": data, "fromPeer": peerID]
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("receivedMPCDataNotification", object: dictionary)
}

func session(session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withProgress progress: NSProgress) { }

func session(session: MCSession, didFinishReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, atURL localURL: NSURL, withError error: NSError?) { }

func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveStream stream: NSInputStream, withName streamName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID) { }
}
```

Comment: Did you copy and paste this code from a tutorial or something?  Perhaps it is outdated.  Your function signatures don't match the required functions; a number of parameters are specified as implicitly unwrapped optionals (!) when they shouldn't be and the function signature for `foundPeer` doesn't match - the dictionary should be `[String: String]` not `[NSObject: AnyObject]` - The error messages and warnings from the compiler explain all of this

Comment: I have just updated the code to have the correct functions.  Still getting the same error.  I followed along with this tutorial: http://www.appcoda.com/chat-app-swift-tutorial/

Comment: You still have errors in your `didReceiveInvitationFromPeer` function.  In Xcode, select the "speech bubble" at the top of the project navigator, then select your build operation, then you can expand the compiler output to see the detailed error messages.  Once you fix the `didReceiveInvitationFromPeer` function you will get errors in your init because it uses `self` before calling `super.init()` - move these lines to after `super.init`

Comment: Thank you Paul, it has been fixed.

Comment: I have fixed the errors. The updated version can be found the link below.https://github.com/runyu/MPCRevisted-Appcoda